# when I install sverchok 5.9.6, the search is blank

Tags: python, sverchok

I still use blender 2.79c and sverchok 5.1.1 ... when I install sverchok 5.9.6, the search is blank. I presume everything else works. I use Windows 10 and my PC has no GPU card installed, so I can't use blender 2.80+. Is there anything I can do with blender 2.79c to correct this?

Comment: ask the addon developer

Comment: OK thank you for the reply